# apache2 server sometimes returns no response but logs a 200 status

Tags: apache

I'm running an Apache2 web server

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar 19 2014 21:11:10
```

Every once in a while it silently fails to return content yet writes a 200 status code to the log file.  For example, here is the regular log entry for a particular file.

```
50.158.90.90 - - [17/Nov/2014:06:18:16 -0800] "GET /beta/images/supported_browsers_64h.png HTTP/1.1" 200 12028 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

But every once in a while an entry like this shows up.

```
50.158.90.90 - - [17/Nov/2014:07:30:38 -0800] "GET /beta/images/supported_browsers_64h.png HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Nothing shows up in the error log when this happens.  Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Etag? conditional get?

Comment: But the 0 includes headers doesn't it?  So nothing at all was returned.  My only thought is that perhaps the client closed the connection early.  But why the 200 status?

Comment: by default (unless you are using something like mod_io) that size is body only, doesn't include headers

Comment: Could also start logging %X